# What do you call this simple test? (sampling from a restricted model)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap

I am looking for the name for statistical tests that proceed the following way (if it exists). For simplicity, assume you estimate the linear regression model:
$$y = \alpha + \beta X + \varepsilon,$$ with $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

I want to test $H_0$: $\beta=0$.
The test proceeds as follows:

1. Estimate the unrestricted model, obtain $\hat{\beta}$
2. Estimate the restricted model imposing $H_0$: $\beta=0$, obtain $\hat{\alpha}_o$ and $\hat{\sigma^2}_o$
3. Draw $B$ data sets from the fitted restricted model from step 2

   - In the example this means: draw $n$ times $\hat{Y}_o \sim N(\hat\alpha_o,\hat{\sigma^2}_o$).
4. Estimate the unrestricted model on each of the $B$ data sets and obtain $B$ estimates $\hat{\beta}_b$.

   - In the example: estimate $B$ regressions of $\hat{Y}_0$ on $X$.
5. Assess what fraction of $|\beta_b|$ is larger than $|\hat{\beta}|$. This is the $p$-value for rejecting $H_0$

I consider this test appealing, because it seems to me to be free of distributional assumptions beyond the model itself and, based on my intuition should produce valid inference. I assume I am not the first person with that idea, so I'd like to find out where to read more on this.

Comment: Could you please explain step 3 a little more. Particularly what does *"... from the fitted restricted model from step 2*" mean? If you are simply sampling from your main dataset, this sounds like [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

Comment: No, not sampling from the data, but drawing new model errors from the assumed distribution. I will edit the text to clarify.

Comment: BTW: I would definitely say this is a form of bootstrapping. But unlike standard boostrapping, this does not obtain the sampling distribution of the (unrestricted) estimate, but somehow imposes the tested restriction / estimated in the process. I don't think this is common in bootstrapping. Is it?

Comment: This sounds like a version of a [parameteric bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Parametric_bootstrap).

Comment: Yes, I think that's precisely what I am describing. If you make this a (short) answer I will mark this as the correct answer to my question.